# How to strip html tags with ids in Perl?

Tags: perl

does any one in here knows on how to strip html tags with Perl when using XML::Simple output ?

Here is the code I have;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::Simple;
$xml = new XML::Simple;
$data = $xml->XMLin('library.xml', ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => {},);

foreach my $library (@{$data->{library}})
{
  foreach my $shelf (@{$library->{shelf}})
  {
    print $xml->XMLout($shelf, RootName => "book", NoSort => 1);
  }
}
```

This code will output something like this;

```
<library>
  <book shelf="12345">Book Title Here</book>
</library>
```

How do I remove     tags, and just keep the title. Perhaps there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated :-) Thank you.

Comment: The topic and first sentence are incongruent the code and example data. Please fix this, it is a bit unclear what you actually want.

Comment: 1) Is this XML or HTML tags? 2) Is there a definite structure to the XML?

Comment: Also, please provide a sample input for that proposed output.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't find anything within XML::Simple for your purposes, why not just remove the tags?

```
    local $_ = $xml->XMLout($shelf, RootName => "book", NoSort => 1);
    s#<.+?>#\n#sg;
    s#\s*\n+\s*#\n#sg;
    print;
```